# NgRx/Effects not triggering the Reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I know the title of the question is vague, but unfortunately I don't exactly know what is causing my issue so please bear with me.

I just started working on a small Angular 8 task, which uses NgRx/Store and NgRx/Effects as well. I am fetching an array of `Book` objects using a `getBooks` function. My codes are as follows(Haven't put inports everywhere just to make the code parts shorter)

**book.component.ts**

```
export class BookComponent {

  constructor(private booksService: BooksService, public store: Store<BooksState>) {
    this.books$ = store.pipe(select('books'));
  }

  books$: Observable<BooksState>;
  BooksSubscription: Subscription;
  booksList: Book[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.BooksSubscription = this.books$
      .pipe( map(x => { this.booksList = x.Books; }) ).subscribe();
    this.store.dispatch(BooksActions.BeginGetBooksAction())
  }
}
```

**book.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import booksData from "../../books.json";

@Injectable()
export class BooksService {
  constructor() { }

  getBooks(){
      return booksData;
  }
}
```

`booksData` is an array of objects of type `Book` which I import from a `json` file.

**book.action.ts**

```
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Book } from "./book";

export const GetBooksAction = createAction("GetBooks");
export const BeginGetBooksAction = createAction("BeginGetBooks");
export const SuccessGetBooksAction = createAction( "SuccessGetBooks", props<{ payload: Book[] }>());
```

**book.reducer.ts**

```
import { Action, createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import * as BooksActions from "./book.action";
import { Book } from "./book";

export interface BooksState {
  Books: Book[];
}

const initialState: BooksState = {
    Books: []
};

const booksReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(BooksActions.GetBooksAction, state => state))
    on(BooksActions.SuccessGetBooksAction, (state: BooksState, { payload }) => {
      console.log(payload)
      return { ...state, Books: payload };
    });

  export function reducer(state: BooksState | undefined, action: Action) {
    return booksReducer(state, action);
  }
```

**book.effect.ts**

Now this is where I'm lost. I found a reference code on the NgRx docs based on which I wrote my code but it does not work

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as BooksActions from './book.action';
import { Book } from './book';
import { BooksService } from './book.service';


@Injectable()
export class BooksEffects {
    constructor(private action$: Actions, private booksService: BooksService) { }

     GetBooks$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
        this.action$.pipe(
            ofType(BooksActions.BeginGetBooksAction),
            mergeMap(
                () => this.booksService.getBooks().pipe(
                    map((booksData: Book[]) => {
                        return BooksActions.SuccessGetBooksAction({ payload: booksData });
                    }))
            )
        )
    )
  );
}
```

I get following errors during compilation. The errors are on the lines where I have `pipe functions`

```
error TS2322: Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action> | ((...args: any[]) 
=> Observable<Action>)'.
      Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'.
        Property 'type' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Action'.
```

---

`error TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type '{ "isbn": string; "title": string; "subtitle": string; "author": string; "published": string; "publisher": string; "pages": number; "description": string; "website": string; }[]'.`

Also, I have added `StoreModule.forRoot({ books: reducer})` and `EffectsModule.forRoot([BooksEffects])` to `imports` and added `BookService` to `Providers` in **app.module.ts**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.

**MergeMap used incorrectly**

Your `this.booksService.getBooks()` seems not to return an `Observable`. In this case, you want to use `map` instead of `mergeMap`:

```
GetBooks$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
   this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(BooksActions.BeginGetBooksAction),
      map(() => this.booksService.getBooks()),
      map(payload => BooksActions.SuccessGetBooksAction({ payload })                
   )
);
```

To elaborate on this, `mergeMap` is used when you want to switch from one Observable to another (similiar to `switchMap`). The callback is expected to return an Observable to which `mergeMap` can then subscribe. The callback for `map` is expected to return a value and wraps that value into a new Observable for you. As you `getBooks()` does not return an Observable, `mergeMap` cannot subscribe to it, TypeScript knows that and throws said errors. 
Alternatively, you could also change your `getBooks()` to return an Observable instead (this would be the way to go if you later want to fetch these from an HTTP Request, which would return an Observable.

**Wrong parenthesis in reducer**

Also, on further inspection, your effects and your reducer are actually running. But you have a small mistake with your paranthesis in your reducer. Look at this:

```
const booksReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(BooksActions.GetBooksAction, state => state))  // <---- This ")" is closing your "createReducer" function!
    on(BooksActions.SuccessGetBooksAction, (state: BooksState, { payload }) => {
      console.log(payload)
      return { ...state, Books: payload };
    });
```

so if you format this to reflect what it's doing you wrote:

```
const booksReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(BooksActions.GetBooksAction, state => state)
)

// You "on" function is actually outside "createReducer" effectively NEVER being triggered (but this is syntactically correct so a very tricky error)
on(BooksActions.SuccessGetBooksAction, (state: BooksState, { payload }) => {
   console.log(payload)
   return { ...state, Books: payload };
});
```

So you just need to fix that one:

```
const booksReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(BooksActions.GetBooksAction, state => state),
    on(BooksActions.SuccessGetBooksAction, (state: any, { payload }) => {
      console.log('Reducer is running, value is:', payload)
      return { ...state, Books: payload };
    })
);
```

Here is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vinw6t). Look into the console to see everything being triggered.

Comment: This got rid of the errors. But my reducer still doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Can you see if the action is dispatched though? So we know if it is a problem with the effect not triggering or with the reducer not reacting.

Comment: @Amruta Updated my answer. Created a working Stackblitz and found an error that prevented your reducer from running correctly

Comment: I modified the app-component. Although the actions are fired. But no data is showing up in the app-component. Do I miss something?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o9yq23

Comment: @Morrowyn Your reducer is not correct - the first function needs to pick of the slice of your state (the one you defined in app.module), the second defines what part of that slice you want to display. Your slice is called `books` not `Books` (mind the lower case). Also, your variable on the template is not named `bookList$` but `books$` - here is your example working (mind, the only places I changed anything are `book.selector.ts` and `app.component.html`): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbbsld?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

`pipe` is a function of `Observable`, but `this.booksService.getBooks()` returns a plain Array instead.

So either don't call `pipe` on the resulting Array or let your service return an `Observable`. An easy way is to return `of(
booksData)`; the `of` function creates an `Observable` from the given value.